# High-pitched, accelerated voice with Logitech C270

Tags: pulseaudio, logitech, audio-recording

I have some issues when recording/videocalling with Logitech C270 USB webcam: my voice is high-pitched, accelerated, squeaky. The odd thing is that this happens sometimes, not always, and independently from software used (Teams, Skype, Meet, Audacity, arecord, audio-recorder, Telegram); every time it happens, I get a

```
usb 1-2: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
```

in `dmesg` output. More information:

- Using audio-recorder I can distinguish when my recording is going to be "bad" because time flows more slowly (a 3 s recording lasts 5-6 s);
- I have the same problem on Kubuntu 18.04 and MX 19.1;
- Restarting pulseaudio by

  ```
  pulseaudio -k
  pulseaudio --start
  ```

  sometimes fixes, sometimes not;
- Setting `-r 16000` when invoking `arecord` doesn't fix (I tried this since many people solved similar issues by changing default sample rate in pulseaudio settings, which I have not tried since my issue is not exactly the same);
- The only application I had no issues with (if I remember correctly) is guvcview: when recording, anyway, `dmesg` complains

  ```
  uvcvideo: Failed to query (SET_CUR) UVC control 4 on unit 1: -32 (exp. 4).
  ```

Please ask for every piece of information you need.

Comment: This worked for me:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229193/high-pitched-accelerated-voice-with-logitech-c270

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but I figured I'd share my input. I have the same issues with the Logitech C270. My best solution is to get a new webcam. I have done lots of googling and experimenting with no luck. It is likely a driver/hardware issue and nothing that we can easily fix.

Answer (score 0):

add to `$HOME/.pulse/daemon.conf line`:

```
default-sample-rate = 16000
```

after that run (or just reboot system):

```
pulseaudio --kill && pulseaudio --start
```

that must fix problem